# Rails Caching Strategy for Index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2, memcached

In my User Index action I am running a query which finds all Users who belong to the same city as the `current_user` and the opposite gender and sorts the result by `profile_update_at` in `DESC` order. The query works just fine. The app is currently running in 3 cities. So every male from City A is essentially running the same query and likewise for females from City A.

I want to be able to cache this query for about 5 minutes. How can I do that? What type of caching should I be using? Since the query depends on the city and the gender of the `current_user`, would the cache created for a User from City A, interfere with a User's query from City B? Or will a new cache be created for a user from City B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Rails.cache (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores). Each combination of city and gender is a unique key fo cache. So in index action you will have something like:
Controller code:

```
def index
    @users = User.same_city_opp_gender_as(current_user)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
end
```

Model code:

```
def self.same_city_opp_gender_as(user)
  Rails.cache.fetch("users/#{user.city}/#{user.gender}"){ User.where(city: user.city).where(gender: user.gender).order(:updated_at) }
end
```

Also User class must provide city and gender methods. 
For 3 cities(A,B,C) and 2 genders(M,F) you will get 6 caches with following keys:

- "users/A/M"
- "users/A/F"
- "users/B/M"
- "users/B/F"
- "users/C/M"
- "users/C/F"

So each call of same_city_opp_gender_as will generate new cache if it misses, or fetch value if cache present. Think about expiration of cache and read https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/building-a-rails-3-application-with-memcache

Comment: You pass city and gender to fetch function. They are used to make cache key. If there is such key in store, the rails will return its value without db query, otherwise it will run the block and save returned value to store.

Comment: it shows that it is caching, but it is re-running the query. Also, it not really caching since if the results are updated within 5 minutes, it is showing the updates.

Comment: @pratski Have you install and set-up memcache? Try Rails.cache without expire_in parameter. Read article that I've mentioned above. You initial question was about cache strategies, I've unswared it. if you have problems with setting up - create new question

Comment: I have installed Memcache. It is actually working for another one of my actions. Do you think it has anything to do with Pagination?

Comment: Paperclip? I didn’t understand that you had said. This gem is for storing files, not for caching

Comment: Or, it can really be. But you should do additional search to be 100% sure